# How does the linker determine which custom sections are read-only?

Tags: c, linker

If you define a custom section for a global variable in C, and define a custom output section in a linker script, how does the linker (?) determine the attributes (W = writable, A = allocatable, ...) for this section?

### Issue and MWE

I am currently facing the issue that I assign the same section to two global variables, where one is constant (in its usage, not the program code) while the other is not. In the end, they both end up in a section that is only allocatable, but not writable, and the program terminates with a segmentation fault.

Example program (`test.c`):

```
static double some_thing[5] __attribute__ ((section ("my_nonconst_section"))) = {2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0};
static double another_thing[5]  __attribute__ ((section ("my_nonconst_section")));

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    another_thing[1] = some_thing[argc];
    return another_thing[argc] == 0.0;
}
```

My custom linker script extension (`linkerscript.ld`, note that the self-defined address is crucial for me, that's why I am using the sections in the first place):

```
SECTIONS {
  . = 0x0000001b000002e0;
  my_nonconst_section : {KEEP(*(my_nonconst_section))}
  /* . = 0xAddressForThisSection;
     my_const_section : {KEEP(*(my_const_section))}
     ... */
}
INSERT AFTER .gnu.attributes;
```

I use clang (tested `10.0.0-4ubuntu1` and self-built 12) to compile/link it with my linker script (clang is also not optional, see below):

`clang -mcmodel=large -O1 test.c -Wl,-Tlinkerscript.ld -o test.tmp`

and then execute it:

`./test.tmp`

However, I noticed that `clang -O0` (where it doesn't derive that `some_thing` is constant) and `gcc` (`9.4.0`, with any optimization level) do not exhibit this behavior.

The linker I use is `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34`, however I can see the same effect with the `gold` linker. I target `x86_64`.

Can I somehow influence which attributes the custom linker sections have (ideally defined in the linker script)? I would be fine to have some variables which are not written in the writable section.

### Context/Background:

I am writing a (LLVM/clang) compiler pass that annotates global variables with custom linker sections. I define the linker output sections for these global variables in a custom linker script (which extends the default linker script by these sections), similar to the one described above.

The pass distinguishes between constant and non-constant global variables by looking at the global variables attributes. In case it is constant, a section label for constants is chosen, and one which contains writable data otherwise. However, *after* adding the section annotation, another compiler pass is able to show that one of the variables -- which is annotated with a (ideologically) non-constant section -- is indeed only read, and hence the pass marks it as constant.

The result is that the section which contains the global variable marked as `const` is made read-only, while it still contains non-constant global variables. During the execution of the program, the attempt to write another global variable in this section results in a segmentation fault (as expected).

I determined that both variables are read-only with `nm`:

```
0000001b00000310 r another_thing
0000001b000002e0 r some_thing
```

The section looks as follows (determined by `readelf -S`):

```
[Nr] Name                    Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
[..] my_nonconst_section     PROGBITS        0000001b000002e0 0032e0 000058 00   A  0   0 16
```

Usually, I would expect the non-constant data section to use `Flg = WA`, and the constant section `Flg = A`.

#### Note

Currently, I do not have to hand-write a full linker script, and the compiler pass is compatible to handle C source code which already has section annotations, it would be great to preserve this property.
I saw that one could fully define the memory layout with the `MEMORY` directive, however to the best of my knowledge, this requires to define the memory for all sections, which I would rather not like to do.
Currently, as I am using "binding" to determine the address for the sections, I cannot (to the best of my knowledge) use binding in combination with named memory, i.e. the attribute feature `> (RW)` to ensure that the section is a writable one.

Comment: I never remember the exact syntax of these linker scripts, but iirc something like `MEMORY { cant_touch_this (r) : ... }` ... `SECTIONS { my_nonconst_section : ... }  > cant_touch_this` might work.

Comment: I would think `my_nonconst_section (aw) : {KEEP(*(my_nonconst_section))}` sets but allocatable and writable attribute, but not sure if that solves the problem here

Comment: @Lundin
Do you know if there is a way to extend the already existing `MEMORY` definition (e.g. for the placement of sections such as `.text` etc) and not having to redefine all of them by hand? I would rather stick to not fully defining `MEMORY` myself, as this seems more invasive than what I need (some global variables assigned to some custom sections). I suppose that it would also be more fragile in the long run. Currently, I only add a couple of sections, and with `MEMORY`, I have to define the entire linker script (if I correctly understood its usage).

Comment: Regarding the attributes at the section definition (@nos):
As far as I understand, these attributes cannot be associated with the section directly (the syntax does not allow for them). To my understanding, this is due to the fact that, e.g., writable is a property of the memory the output section is assigned to, and not the section itself. If I try the proposed solution, I get the error: `/usr/bin/ld:linkerscript.ld:3: non constant or forward reference address expression for section my_nonconst_section`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Achievement unlocked: It Was, In Fact, The Compiler — Trigger a bug in your compiler.*

This is not the linker’s doing, it’s the compiler’s.

The linker just merges the sections it’s been told to merge, together with their attributes (taking the maximum of the permissions in case of mismatch), then lays them out into executable segments; or in the case of a relocatable link, simply merges identically-named sections (with the same behaviour for attributes).

It’s the compiler’s job to put your program’s variables into sections and assign appropriate attributes to those sections. Unfortunately, it seems that Clang 13 and earlier get confused when the user requests that variables that require different section attributes go into the same section. It’s clearer if you look at the object file before linking:

```
$ nix shell 'nixpkgs#binutils' 'nixpkgs#clang_13'
$ clang -mcmodel=large -O1 -c test.c
$ readelf -S test.o
There are 11 section headers, starting at offset 0x2a8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
[...]
  [ 3] .rela.text        RELA             0000000000000000  000001d0
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018          10     2     8
  [ 4] my_nonconst_[...] PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000080
       0000000000000058  0000000000000000   A       0     0     16
  [ 5] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000d8
       0000000000000016  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
[...]
$ ^D
```

(I tried to see if you could work around this by declaring `another_thing`, which requires a `WA` section, first. You can’t, and `some_thing` even ends up with a lower address anyway.)

Clang 14 and up deals with this correctly, if confusingly, by producing two identically-named sections with different attributes:

```
$ nix shell 'nixpkgs#binutils' 'nixpkgs#clang_14'
$ clang -mcmodel=large -O1 -c test.c
$ readelf -S test.o
There are 12 section headers, starting at offset 0x2c0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
[...]
  [ 3] .rela.text        RELA             0000000000000000  000001e8
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      11     2     8
  [ 4] my_nonconst_[...] PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000080
       0000000000000028  0000000000000000   A       0     0     16
  [ 5] my_nonconst_[...] PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000b0
       0000000000000028  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     16
  [ 6] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000d8
       0000000000000016  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
[...]
$ ^D
```

If you then link this object file into an executable, then in the former and buggy case `my_nonconst_section` ends up with attributes `A` (duh), so you get a segfault, while in the latter and correct case it ends up with `WA` (due to the merging), so the executable works correctly.

**P. S.** Funnily enough, because the GNU assembler is incapable of supporting identically-named sections in a single object and LLVM-MC follows suit, the non-buggy object file from `clang -c` now does not match the assembler source printed by `clang -S`, as the latter uses `.section my_nonconst_section,"aw",@progbits` before declaring both variables in one go.